# How do I approach this Linux C++ warning? "can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `sockaddr_in'"

Tags: c++, eclipse, linker-warning

Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit, eclipse, C and C++

I have a program that uses select() to monitor a bunch of TCP and UDP ports.  I create those ports in the usual way (socket(), bind(), listen(), accept() etc.) using **sockaddr_in** structures.

The program works fine at the command line.  I was using the eclipse debugger to fix a bug (fixed now!) when I noticed the following warning:

```
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `sockaddr_in' value
warning:   found `operator delete(void*)' instead
```

Well, after fixing my bug I checked and the warning persisted.

I know that the warnings commence as soon as I enter my ConfigureServer() routine where the ports/sockets get connected.  The sockaddr_in structures are declared in the routine and are on the stack. In fact, nothing in the program is yet in the heap.  This is a mix of C and C++ with no objects declared or used up to this point.

This is the beginning odf the routine.  There are several additional identical bits for other ports.

```
int      configureServer()
{
   sockaddr_in         servAddr; 

   memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
   servAddr.sin_family        = AF_INET;        
   servAddr.sin_port          = htons( g_tcpPorts[0].serverPort ); 
   servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr   = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 

   /* Create and initialize the TCP socket */
   if (( g_tcpPorts[0].serverSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP)) < 0 )
   {
      PLOG( ERROR ) << "failed to acquire a socket for IO Control Server port:  " << g_tcpPorts[0].serverPort;
      return -1;     // caller will CloseAllPorts();
   } 

// ...........
}
```

So, my question is, how do I debug and track down the cause of these warnings.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems you are missing a header file.

Comment: Don't worry, it's a (harmless) bug in GDB.

Comment: @n.m.  That's great news.  If you'll post it as an answer I'll give it a vote-up and a best answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB is still less than perfect, especially when it comes to debugging C++ code.

In this case, `sockaddr_in` is "plain old data" (a C struct without any C++ features). It does not need and should not have any virtual table. If GDB thinks otherwise, that's a problem with GDB.

[There are two bugs open in GDB bug database that quite this exact message](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=warning%3A+can%27t+find+linker+symbol+for+virtual+table) (for different structs/classes). I would not worry about it too much unless it gets in the way of your debugging.

Comment: Do you know if this bug with gdb persists? I am getting this same warning with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe using extern "C" before including the headers that declare the sockadd_in struct.

```
extern "C"
{
#  include <netinet/in.h>
}
```

That will probably insure sockaddr_in won't have or need a vtab.