# What could be the cause for runtime "can't find linker symbol for virtual table..." error in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, vtable

This question was asked in similar ways multiple times, for example at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544120/memory-violation-sigsegv-and-cant-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual-table) or [forum.qt.io](http://forum.qt.io/topic/4457/can-t-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual-table/12) or [qtcentre.org](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50592-can-t-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual-table-for-QString-Data-value). The problem is that this error message is so vague that one solution cannot be applied to another scenario. Most of the threads are dead in the middle of the discussion though :-(

So the complete error message that I get in my Qt application is:

**can't find linker symbol for virtual table for "OneOfMyClasses" 
value
found "QString::shared_null" instead**

The *OneOfMyClasses* changes depending on various things, the *QString::shared_null* stays the same for all errors that I get. Here is a screenshot of my logging console:

[image]

1. Why is the font color pink, so who is printing this message?
2. Why do I only see this message when I set a breakpoint and step through my code? This message does not appear when simply running the application.

The point where it happens is in this function in the source line right before the current position (yellow arrow):

[image]

So according to the message I stepped into `m_pStateWidget->insertNavLabel(...)` and the error message is printed somewhere in the constructors inside Qt related to the QString class. So I tried the following, which moves the problem away from this code location:

[image]

When doing this I get the same error message a few code lines below with another class name in the message, note that the *QString::shared_null* stays the same.

It appears to me that I have some sort of corrupted memory.

3. How should I start investigating this issue? I'm afraid to change the code because this might hide the problem as described above.
4. What's up with the QString::shared_null? I have found that others often see the same in their error messages.

Thank you for any hint or help! :-)

**Edit**: It's becoming really interesting now. I have stepped into every single function just right before the message is printed and I ended up with these error messages:

[image]

at this location:

[image]

When I navigate through the call stack in QtCreator the error is printed again and again everytime I select another function in the stack.

5. Does this mean that the debugger is printing the message and that it is simply too stupid to resolve some sort of vtable stuff for me or does this mean that I have serious trouble going on?

Comment: It looks like a problem with QtCreator and its debugger, not with your code.

Comment: That's a possibility because I don't run in any seg faults or index range problems anywhere. It's also the same conclusion of this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227847/how-do-i-approach-this-linux-c-warning-cant-find-linker-symbol-for-virtual?answertab=active#tab-top). Since I'm developing on an embedded device I have to be really sure what the cause is though.

Comment: It looks like it's a GDB bug. Do any of the classes mentioned in the error messages have virtual functions?

Comment: Yes. When not stepping into all the Qt details my own classes are reported in the error message. Those are structs that also inherit from each other because I need an OOP structure but I don't need encapsulation on them. In addition everything was in a single source file because the objects are actually quite dumb (POD objects in a hierarchy). I now changed all of them to classes and seperated them in .h and .cpp files. The error messages are exactly the same though.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are structs or classes and in what files they are declared. The question is, are there virtual functions. POD doesn't have virtual function.

Comment: Since they are in a OOP hierarchy they have a virtual destructor. So they are not PODs. My approach of putting them into different files and transforming them into classes was just an attempt to play with GDB, which didn't change anything.

Comment: I think it can also happen if all virtual functions are inline, not sure. Try moving the dtor out of line.

Comment: It is declared in .h and defined in .cpp.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have similar error...

Comment: @TomášZato Unfortunately not. I'm running into this issue from time to time when i step through different pieces of my code. It really seems to be a problem of the debugger, not the actual code. My personal conclusion is therefore the same as in the thread I linked in the comments above.

Comment: I fixed it. I was accessing memory I shouldn't have, but for some reason debugger didn't notice and let the program continue. In particular, I was accessing indexes outside `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause:**
Somewhere in your code , you might have overrun the actual memory

**Example 1 :**

```
int elmArray[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
elmArray[i] = 0;
}
```

In the above case, actual array size is 10 but we are assigning values to the index beyond 10.

**Example 2:**

```
char* cpyString;

strcpy(cpyString , "TEST");
```

These scenarios might end up in writing the values into other objects. Mostly could corrupt the virtual table.This gives the above warning.

**Fix:**
As you know, just correct the code as below.
Example :

```
int elmArray[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
elmArray[i] = 0;
}

char cpyString[10];
strcpy(cpyString , "TEST");
```

**In your case seems like, you are assigning the QTString::shared_null to some uninitialized string.**

Comment: Hi Raams, thanks for your response. Unfortunately it is not the problem. I can run into such strange warnings even when setting a breakpoint to the constructor of the Qt application. The text of the "vtable" error changes but the concept is always the same. I still expect that problem to come from the debugger or a problem with the Qt library source files in my setup.

Answer (score 2):

There are various threads on different websites where the

> can not find linker symbol for virtual table

problem is discussed. Few explain why the problem exists, although some solutions are given to specific examples.  Having experienced difficulty with this, I would like to share what I have learned.

First this error message only appeared for Linux builds, it did not show up for Windows builds.

In my case the problem was caused by a second call into a non-reentrant method from the same thread.  Once I found the problem, it was easy to fix by using a static busy flag, and simply returning when busy was called a second time.  In a nutshell that was the problem and solution.  But how did I get into this mess?

Well the non-rentrant method was actually a Qt slot.  Since I knew there was a possibility of the second call (actually an emit) being made from the first, the connect was set up with `Qt::QueuedConnection`.  However, I later put up a splash screen `QSplashScreen` while the function was processing.  Little did I realize that `QSplashScreen::repaint()` called `QApplication::processEvents()` which dispatched the second offending emit.

So I could have fixed the problem by removing the `QSplashScreen` and using a `QLabel`. However, while either works nicely in Windows, neither actually works in Linux, they put up a semi-transparent window and don't paint the contents (even repaint() and or `processEvents()` doesn't do it).  So that is probably a Qt Linux bug, which is another story.